# How Can Get Data From Three Tables (JOIN) in Django?

Tags: python, django

We have three Models as below.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class CategoryManager(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name=_('Course Category'), related_name="category_categorymanager")
    manager = models.ForeignKey(_user, verbose_name=_('Category Manager'), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_categorymanager")

class Course(models.Model):   
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=_('Course Name'))
    ...
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, verbose_name=_('Course Price'), blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='courses_category', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

We want to filter courses by the CategoryManager.

```
@admin.register(Course)
class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        category_manager_list=CategoryManager.objects.filter(manager=request.user)
        ... 
        return ....
```

Using the category_manager_list obtained like above, we want to list all courses belonging to these categories.

Comment: 3- show what you have tried.

Comment: you should do it in `views.py` when you get user's request. But you didn't show your `views.py`.

Comment: I edited the question, we use admin.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
@admin.register(Course)
class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return Course.objects.filter(
            category__category_categorymanager__manager=request.user
        ).distinct()
```

---

> **Note**: Your `CategoryManager` model acts as a junction table for a many-to-many relation between `Category` and `_user`. You can span a
> [**`ManyToManyField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField)
> on the `Category` model with:
>
> ```
> class Category(models.Model):
>     # …
>     managers = models.ManyToManyField(
>         _user,
>         through='CategoryManager'
>     )
> ```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).